# How to insert the result of the select query in another table's column

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

```
SELECT segment_name TABLE_NAME, SUM(bytes) table_size
  FROM USER_SEGMENTS
 WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
 GROUP BY segment_name
 ORDER BY segment_name ASC;

INSERT INTO R_LOG (DOMAINID, SOURCENAME, TERMINALID,userid, DETAILTEXT)
VALUES (1, 'tables_job', 'TEST', 'GUEST',?????);
```

I want to store the query output (two columns) in a `DETAILTEXT` column (single column) of `R_LOG` table

```
SELECT segment_name TABLE_NAME, SUM(bytes) table_size
  FROM USER_SEGMENTS
 WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
 GROUP BY segment_name
 ORDER BY segment_name ASC;
```

This part of my code is working totally fine - but I'm not able to insert the value.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need `LISTAGG()` function along with an `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO R_LOG
SELECT 1, 'tables_job', 'TEST', 'GUEST', 
       LISTAGG('Table : '||segment_name||'- size: '|| SUM(bytes),', ') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY segment_name)
  FROM USER_SEGMENTS
 WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
 GROUP BY segment_name
```

If you get **ORA-01489**: *result of string concatenation is too long* error, then replace the last column containing `LISTAGG()` function with

```
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, 'Table : '||segment_name||'- size: '|| SUM(bytes), ',')
      .EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY segment_name)
      .GetClobVal(),
      ',')
```

Comment: @tej have a look at the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=021a578d38e9c9df88041684ee72e190) please, what's the problem ..? Btw, `DETAILTEXT` is of type CLOB, or what's the length of it if the type is VARCHAR2 ..?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to concatenate the columns `segment_name` and `SUM(bytes)` in the destination column.
Use `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO R_LOG (DOMAINID, SOURCENAME, TERMINALID,userid, DETAILTEXT) 
SELECT 1, 'tables_job', 'TEST', 'GUEST', segment_name || ' ' || SUM(bytes) 
FROM USER_SEGMENTS
WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE'
GROUP BY segment_name
ORDER BY segment_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME>[(columns)] SELECT ..` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO R_LOG (
    DOMAINID,
    SOURCENAME,
    TERMINALID,
    USERID,
    DETAILTEXT
)
    SELECT 1, -- need to use some sequence here
           'tables_job',
           'TEST',
           'GUEST',
           SEGMENT_NAME || ' ' || SUM(BYTES)
      FROM USER_SEGMENTS
     WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
     GROUP BY SEGMENT_NAME; 
     -- Order by is not needed
```